# Python 2.5 MemoryError with large file

Tags: python

I can't read a big file because of MemoryError. Other answers suggest this should work, what may be the problem?
The whole code is this

```
#Separador de RAMAS.csv por rama
import csv
archivo_original = open('RAMAS.csv')
print archivo_original.readline()
```

And the error I get is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Separador_CSV.py", line 4, in <module>
    print archivo_original.readline()
MemoryError
```

Comment: How long are the lines?!

Comment: Maybe use `file.read(size_in_bytes)` to read the file (and super-long lines) in chunks?

Comment: Lines should be 200 characters long maximum. Smaller files are correctly opened with Notepad++ and Excel.

Comment: I'm working in Windows 7, file was created in other Python script with no problem, with lineterminator = '\r'

Comment: `file.readline` does not seem to split on `\r`. If you created that file with another Python script, better create it again with `\n` instead of `\r`, then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working in Windows 7, file was created in other Python script with no problem, with lineterminator = '\r'

`file.readline` does not seem to split on `\r`. If you created that file with another Python script, better create it again with `\n` instead of `\r`, then it should work.

Example with `\r`:

```
In [14]: open("test", "w").write("foo\rbar\rblub")
In [15]: open("test", "r").readline()
Out[15]: 'foo\rbar\rblub'
```

Example with `\n`:

```
In [16]: open("test", "w").write("foo\nbar\nblub")
In [17]: open("test", "r").readline()
Out[17]: 'foo\n'
```

If that's not possible, you can use `file.read(size_in_bytes)` to read just a chunk of the file and re-create the lines yourself.

Comment: Isn't there a way to tell Python to interpret \r as newline?

Comment: @José Not sure, I think there _should_ be, but I could not find such a parameter on `open` or `file.read`.

Comment: @José I think you could use a `csv.reader` and configure an according dialect. Even if the file is not CSV, you could read it as a CSV file with just one column.

Answer (score 0):

I've found Python interprets the file as being one big line.
Thanks for the comments, made me find the problem.